# SimpleWPFReporting's PDF has no content

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I'm trying to generate a very simple PDF just for practice by using [SimpleWPFReporting](https://github.com/maximcus/SimpleWPFReporting).

Since there is no sample code in its documentation, I tried creating a sample from what I understood:

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class Sample
    {
        private string _aw;
        public string Aw
        {
            get { return _aw; }
            set { _aw = value; }
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel stkMain = new StackPanel();
        stkMain.Background = Brushes.Pink;
        stkMain.Height = 100;
        stkMain.Width = 100;

        TextBlock txtSample = new TextBlock();
        txtSample.Text = "SAMPLE TEXT";
        stkMain.Children.Add(txtSample);
        ReportOrientation portrait = ReportOrientation.Portrait;
        Sample sample = new Sample()
        {
            Aw = "Some text"
        };

        Report.ExportReportAsPdf(stkMain, sample, portrait);
    }
}
```

It does save as a PDF, but when I open it, it's blank. What I'm expecting is to see at least the `TextBlock` there.

I don't really understand the use of data context in the arguments, so I just added a class there. I tried looking for tutorials but failed. Did I miss something or did I create it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to specify the stackpanel orientation as "vertical", as stated in the doc

https://github.com/maximcus/SimpleWPFReporting

Answer (score 0):

After digging in to the [source](https://github.com/maximcus/SimpleWPFReporting/blob/master/SimpleWPFReporting/Report.cs) code, it uses a Visual,so you have to add the stackpanel to the visual tree in order to be renderer and then printed.

You can create a previewer window, add the stackpanel and now the pdf will show the content.

I will create a previewer by myself, so I will post when I finish it.